# R Aggregate multiple rows

Tags: r, row, aggregate

My question seems to be a very common question, but the solutions I found on internet don't work...

I would like to aggregate rows in a data frame in R.
Here is the structure of my data frame (df), it is a table of citations :

```
Autors      Lannoy_2016  Ramadier_2014  Lord_2009  Ortar_2008
Burgess E             1             NA         NA          NA
Burgess E             1             NA         NA          NA
Burgess E             1             NA         NA          NA
Burgess E             1             NA         NA          NA
Kaufmann V           NA              1         NA          NA
Kaufmann V           NA             NA          1          NA
Kaufmann V           NA             NA         NA           1
Orfeuil P             1             NA         NA          NA
Orfeuil P            NA              1         NA          NA
Sorokin P            NA             NA         NA           1
```

That is I would like to have :

```
Autors      Lannoy_2016  Ramadier_2014  Lord_2009  Ortar_2008
Burgess E             4             NA         NA          NA
Kaufmann V           NA              1          1           1
Orfeuil P             1              1         NA          NA
Sorokin P            NA             NA         NA           1
```

I have tried those solutions, but it doesn't work :

```
ddply(df,"Autors", numcolwise(sum))
```

and

```
df %>% group_by(Autors) %>% summarize_all(sum)
```

It aggregates well the rows, but the values (sum of the 1 values) are absolutely not correct ! And I don't understand why...

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you very much !

Joël

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because the `na.rm` is not used

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Autors) %>% 
   summarize_all(sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

if both `plyr` and `dplyr` are loaded, `summarise` would get masked, but doubt about `summarise_all` as it is a `dplyr` function

Based on the expected output, with `na.rm = TRUE`, it removes all `NA`s and if there are cases having only `NA`s it returns 0.  To avoid that, we can have a condition

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Autors) %>% 
   summarize_all(funs(if(all(is.na(.))) NA else sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Autors     Lannoy_2016 Ramadier_2014 Lord_2009 Ortar_2008
#  <chr>            <int>         <int>     <int>      <int>
#1 Burgess E            4            NA        NA         NA
#2 Kaufmann V          NA             1         1          1
#3 Orfeuil P            1             1        NA         NA
#4 Sorokin P           NA            NA        NA          1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Autors = c("Burgess E", "Burgess E", "Burgess E", 
"Burgess E", "Kaufmann V", "Kaufmann V", "Kaufmann V", "Orfeuil P", 
"Orfeuil P", "Sorokin P"), Lannoy_2016 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
 NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), Ramadier_2014 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
 NA, NA, 1L, NA), Lord_2009 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 
 NA, NA), Ortar_2008 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L
 )), .Names = c("Autors", "Lannoy_2016", "Ramadier_2014", "Lord_2009", 
 "Ortar_2008"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working, the problem was of course the NA !

Answer (score 3):

You can also do the summing using **rowsum()**, although it (perhaps misleadingly) gives sums of 0 rather than NA for cells in the output that had only NA's for input.

```
 rowsum(df[,c(2:5)],df$Autors,na.rm=T)
```

Gives:

```
            Lannoy_2016 Ramadier_2014 Lord_2009 Ortar_2008
 Burgess E            4             0         0          0
 Kaufmann V           0             1         1          1
 Orfeuil P            1             1         0          0
 Sorokin P            0             0         0          1
```